# swagger express ui strips the prefix and redirects to host

Tags: express, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

I am not able to load swagger for my nestJS application which is deployed on EKS.

Here is my main.ts

```
import {NestFactory} from '@nestjs/core';
import {NestExpressApplication} from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import {DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule} from '@nestjs/swagger';
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express')
import {AppModule} from './app.module';
import {json, NextFunction, Request, Response} from 'express';

(async () => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
      .setTitle('Test')
      .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options,{ ignoreGlobalPrefix: true 
 

  app.use("*/docs",swaggerUi.serve,swaggerUi.setup(document));

  // Or 
  SwaggerModule.setup(`/docs`, app, document);

 
  await app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Test service is running on port ${port}...`);
  });
})
();
```

On my local machine the swagger doc loads correctly but when I deploy it to a development environment, it fails

dev url "https://dev-test-api.com/testservice/v1/docs/", it strips the /testservice/v1/ and redirects to "https://dev-test-api.com/docs/ and gives a 404.

I have tried couple of solutions mentioned in https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/issues/183

The forward-prefix option and the redirect too. None seem to work

Another problem I have is that the prefix "testservice/v1" changes as per different sandbox environments and since it is not an environment variable I don't have a way to set the path for swagger file before app is loaded.

Comment: try removing the / before docs like 'SwaggerModule.setup(`"docs"`, app, document);' i am not sure if it will work but that is how redirecting works a  '/' redirects it to the actual url but if you remove it, it redirects to the controller path

Comment: @SiddheshKhadapkar thank you for your reply, I tried removing the slash, but it did not work